# Is there a way to loop a CSS keyframe sequence?

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm trying to loop this SVG animation sequence, ideally in alternate direction on an infinite basis. I have tried:

```css
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
```

I can apply these properties to the elements but not for the entire sequence. I don't seem to be able to find a solution which reverses and/or restarts the full sequence. Is there a solution?

```css
#santander {
  animation: fadeInDown 1s normal forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 500ms;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#skeleton-1 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#skeleton-2 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 1000ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#barclays {
  animation: fadeInDown 1s normal forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 1500ms;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#skeleton-3 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 1700ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#skeleton-4 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 2000ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#hsbc {
  animation: fadeInDown 1s normal forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 2500ms;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#skeleton-5 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 2700ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#skeleton-6 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 3000ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#halifax {
  animation: fadeInDown 1s normal forwards;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 3500ms;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#skeleton-8 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 3700ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

#skeleton-7 {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: slideLeft 1s normal forwards;
  animation-delay: 4000ms;
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="320" height="500" viewBox="0 0 347 468" fill="none" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="Phone">
<g id="Phone_2">
<g id="Phone_3" filter="url(#filter0_d_526_109)">
<rect x="34" y="29" width="279" height="400" rx="25" fill="#F0F2F6" fill-opacity="0.7" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
<rect x="29.625" y="24.625" width="287.75" height="408.75" rx="29.375" stroke="white" stroke-width="8.75" shape-rendering="crispEdges"/>
</g>
<g id="halifax">
<g id="container-4" filter="url(#filter1_d_526_109)">
<rect x="47" y="322" width="253.75" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
</g>
<rect id="skeleton-8" x="132" y="335.75" width="156.25" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="skeleton-7" x="132" y="365.75" width="100" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="mask-4" x="47" y="322" width="85" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
<g id="halifax-logo">
<path d="M64.5 347C64.5 340.096 70.0964 334.5 77 334.5H102C108.904 334.5 114.5 340.096 114.5 347V372C114.5 378.904 108.904 384.5 102 384.5H77C70.0964 384.5 64.5 378.904 64.5 372V347Z" fill="#005EB8"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M77.4718 358.727H75.4807V356.33H74.123V362.178H75.4807V359.961H77.4718V362.178H78.8379V356.33H77.4718V358.727Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M86.5388 356.33H85.1728V362.178H88.658V360.945H86.5388L86.5388 356.33Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M89.2917 362.178H90.6741V356.33H89.2917V362.178Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M92.8192 357.563H95.3927V356.33H91.4533V362.178H92.8192V359.961H94.9516V358.727H92.8192V357.563Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M81.3826 359.961L82.0053 357.983L82.628 359.961H81.3826ZM81.2581 356.33L79.2806 362.178H80.6845L81.0191 361.116H82.9915L83.3261 362.178H84.7301L82.7545 356.33H81.2581Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M97.0771 359.961L97.6998 357.983L98.3225 359.961H97.0771ZM105.509 356.33H103.96L102.859 358.097L101.758 356.33H100.208L102.116 359.254L100.351 361.96L98.449 356.33H96.9525L94.975 362.178H96.3789L96.7135 361.116H98.6861L99.0207 362.178H101.758L102.859 360.411L103.96 362.178H105.509L103.602 359.254L105.509 356.33Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M74 349H85.6078L91.4532 355.175H80.414L74 349Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M90.5513 352.759L94.1719 349H105.78L99.3658 355.175H92.8386L90.5513 352.759Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M90.5514 365.749L92.8388 363.333H99.3659L105.78 369.508H94.172L90.5514 365.749Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M91.4533 363.333H80.4141L74.0035 369.504L85.6079 369.508L91.4533 363.333Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<g id="hsbc">
<g id="container-3" filter="url(#filter2_d_526_109)">
<rect x="47" y="235" width="253.75" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
</g>
<rect id="skeleton-6" x="132" y="278.75" width="100" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="skeleton-5" x="132" y="248.75" width="156.25" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="mask-3" x="47" y="235" width="85" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
<g id="hsbc-logo">
<path d="M64.5 260C64.5 253.096 70.0964 247.5 77 247.5H102C108.904 247.5 114.5 253.096 114.5 260V285C114.5 291.904 108.904 297.5 102 297.5H77C70.0964 297.5 64.5 291.904 64.5 285V260Z" fill="white"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M79.489 281.396H100.832V260.053H79.489V281.396Z" fill="#FFFFFE"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M79.489 260.037H100.831L90.1604 270.708L79.489 260.037Z" fill="#DB352A"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M79.489 281.378H100.831L90.1604 270.708L79.489 281.378Z" fill="#DB352A"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M79.489 260.037V281.378L68.817 270.708L79.489 260.037Z" fill="#DB352A"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M100.831 260.037V281.378L111.503 270.708L100.831 260.037Z" fill="#DB352A"/>
</g>
</g>
<g id="barclays">
<g id="container-2" filter="url(#filter3_d_526_109)">
<rect x="47" y="148" width="253.75" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
</g>
<rect id="skeleton-4" x="132" y="191.75" width="100" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="skeleton-3" x="132" y="161.75" width="156.25" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="mask-2" x="47" y="148" width="85" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
<g id="barclays-logo">
<path d="M64.5 173C64.5 166.096 70.0964 160.5 77 160.5H102C108.904 160.5 114.5 166.096 114.5 173V198C114.5 204.904 108.904 210.5 102 210.5H77C70.0964 210.5 64.5 204.904 64.5 198V173Z" fill="#00AEEF"/>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M102.59 177.917C102.33 177.309 101.895 176.614 101.113 176.093C100.766 175.833 100.332 175.572 99.8974 175.398C99.5498 175.312 99.2027 175.224 98.7682 175.224H98.6816C98.1602 175.224 97.205 175.311 96.6839 176.093C96.4233 176.354 96.3364 176.875 96.4233 177.309C96.5099 177.657 96.7708 178.004 97.1184 178.091C97.1184 178.091 97.205 178.178 97.3789 178.178C97.3789 178.265 97.2919 178.438 97.2919 178.438C97.0314 178.698 96.5969 179.133 95.2942 179.133H95.2072C94.5126 179.046 93.9915 178.873 93.2098 178.091C92.7754 177.57 92.5148 176.614 92.5148 175.137C92.5148 174.356 92.4278 173.748 92.2543 173.227C92.1673 172.879 91.8202 172.532 91.5592 172.358C91.2987 172.184 91.1251 172.098 90.6906 171.924C90.1692 171.837 89.6481 171.75 89.214 171.75C88.6929 171.75 88.3454 171.837 88.1718 172.098H87.6507L86.7821 172.184C86.2607 172.271 85.9135 172.532 85.5657 172.792C85.4791 172.879 85.1315 173.227 85.0446 173.574C85.0446 173.834 85.1312 174.095 85.1312 174.182L85.2181 174.268C85.3921 174.095 85.7392 174.008 86.1737 174.008C86.7814 174.008 87.65 174.268 87.8239 174.703C88.2581 175.398 88.0841 175.919 88.0841 176.527C87.8239 178.177 87.2159 178.959 85.9128 179.133C85.6523 179.22 85.3917 179.22 85.2178 179.22C84.2626 179.22 83.5675 178.959 83.22 178.351V178.177C83.22 178.177 83.307 178.177 83.394 178.09C83.7411 177.917 84.0017 177.656 84.0886 177.309C84.1752 176.875 84.0886 176.44 83.8285 176.093C83.3074 175.572 82.612 175.224 81.8303 175.224C81.3093 175.224 80.9618 175.311 80.6142 175.398C79.5717 175.658 78.6165 176.527 77.9218 177.917C77.4008 178.959 77.0532 180.175 76.9666 181.565C76.8797 182.955 76.8797 184.084 76.9666 185.126C77.0532 186.863 77.4008 187.905 77.8352 189.035C78.2694 190.164 78.7904 191.206 79.3981 192.162C79.5721 192.422 79.659 192.683 79.8326 192.857L79.9196 192.77C80.0062 192.683 80.0932 192.596 80.1798 192.422C80.5273 192.162 81.1353 191.293 81.3089 191.033C81.4828 190.772 81.7434 190.338 81.917 189.904L82.0036 189.73L82.1775 189.817C82.3511 189.991 82.438 190.251 82.438 190.512C82.438 190.772 82.3511 191.033 82.1775 191.554C82.0036 192.162 81.656 192.857 81.3089 193.552C81.3955 193.639 81.3955 193.812 81.3089 193.812C81.0484 194.246 81.0484 194.42 81.0484 194.594H81.135C81.2216 194.594 81.5691 194.508 81.83 194.246C82.0902 194.073 82.7852 193.465 83.6538 192.249C84.3488 191.38 84.7833 190.425 85.3044 189.383L85.391 189.209L85.5646 189.296L85.8251 189.469C85.9121 189.643 85.9121 189.903 85.9121 190.164C85.8251 190.859 85.391 191.814 85.1301 192.509C84.609 193.726 83.6538 195.029 82.9588 195.984C82.9588 196.07 82.7848 196.244 82.6982 196.244C82.7848 196.331 82.8722 196.418 83.0457 196.505L83.3063 196.765C84.2618 197.547 85.1301 198.155 86.2592 198.763C87.1282 199.284 88.8654 200.152 90.0815 200.5C91.2972 200.24 93.0344 199.284 93.9034 198.763C95.0325 198.155 95.9008 197.547 96.8567 196.765L97.1169 196.505L97.4644 196.244C97.5514 196.07 97.5514 195.984 97.5514 195.897L97.4644 195.81C96.7694 194.941 95.8142 193.552 95.2927 192.335C95.0325 191.641 94.5981 190.685 94.5111 189.991C94.4245 189.73 94.5111 189.469 94.5981 189.296L94.7716 189.122C94.8582 189.035 95.0322 189.035 95.0322 189.035L95.1188 189.209C95.6399 190.251 96.1613 191.206 96.769 192.075C97.638 193.291 98.3326 193.899 98.5932 194.073C98.8537 194.333 99.1143 194.42 99.2882 194.42H99.3752C99.4618 194.334 99.3752 194.16 99.1143 193.725C99.0277 193.639 99.0276 193.552 99.0276 193.465C98.6805 192.77 98.3326 192.075 98.1591 191.467C97.9851 190.946 97.8985 190.598 97.8985 190.425C97.8985 190.164 97.9851 189.903 98.1591 189.73L98.3326 189.643L98.4192 189.817C98.5932 190.251 98.9407 190.772 99.1143 191.033L100.157 192.335C100.331 192.509 100.417 192.596 100.417 192.683L100.504 192.77C100.591 192.683 100.678 192.509 100.851 192.162L100.938 192.075C101.46 191.206 101.981 190.077 102.415 188.948C102.849 187.906 103.11 186.777 103.284 185.04C103.37 183.997 103.457 182.868 103.284 181.479C103.372 180.175 103.024 178.873 102.59 177.917Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<g id="santander">
<g id="container-1" filter="url(#filter4_d_526_109)">
<rect x="47" y="61" width="253.75" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
</g>
<rect id="skeleton-2" x="132" y="104.75" width="100" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="skeleton-1" x="132" y="74.75" width="156.25" height="18.75" rx="5" fill="#E1E1E1"/>
<rect id="mask-1" x="47" y="61" width="85" height="75" rx="10" fill="white"/>
<g id="santander-logo">
<path d="M64.5 86C64.5 79.0964 70.0964 73.5 77 73.5H102C108.904 73.5 114.5 79.0964 114.5 86V111C114.5 117.904 108.904 123.5 102 123.5H77C70.0964 123.5 64.5 117.904 64.5 111V86Z" fill="#D80000"/>
<path d="M95.8778 96.1965C95.8179 95.2976 95.5781 94.3986 95.0987 93.6196L91.0235 86.488C90.7239 85.9486 90.4841 85.3493 90.3643 84.75L90.1845 85.0496C89.1657 86.7876 89.1657 89.005 90.1845 90.7429L93.4806 96.4363C94.4994 98.1742 94.4994 100.392 93.4806 102.13L93.3008 102.429C93.181 101.83 92.9412 101.231 92.6416 100.691L89.6451 95.4774L87.7274 92.1213C87.4277 91.582 87.188 90.9827 87.0682 90.3834L86.8884 90.683C85.8696 92.421 85.8696 94.5784 86.8884 96.3763L90.1845 102.07C91.2033 103.808 91.2033 106.025 90.1845 107.763L90.0047 108.063C89.8848 107.463 89.6451 106.864 89.3455 106.325L85.2103 99.193C84.671 98.2341 84.4313 97.1554 84.4313 96.0767C80.0564 97.2153 77 99.6724 77 102.489C77 106.444 82.8731 109.621 90.1246 109.621C97.376 109.621 103.249 106.444 103.249 102.489C103.309 99.7923 100.313 97.3352 95.8778 96.1965Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_d_526_109" x="0.25" y="0.25" width="346.5" height="467.5" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="5"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="12.5"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.25 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_526_109"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_526_109" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter1_d_526_109" x="40.75" y="318.25" width="266.25" height="87.5" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="2.5"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.125"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_526_109"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_526_109" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter2_d_526_109" x="40.75" y="231.25" width="266.25" height="87.5" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="2.5"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.125"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_526_109"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_526_109" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter3_d_526_109" x="40.75" y="144.25" width="266.25" height="87.5" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="2.5"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.125"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_526_109"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_526_109" result="shape"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter4_d_526_109" x="40.75" y="57.25" width="266.25" height="87.5" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0" result="hardAlpha"/>
<feOffset dy="2.5"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.125"/>
<feComposite in2="hardAlpha" operator="out"/>
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.15 0"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow_526_109"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow_526_109" result="shape"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your CSS. For example, why are there multiple @keyframes slideLeft?